# Moving to the US from Canada - what are the tax implications from both ends on CAD saving account?

Tags: savings-account, cad-canadian-dollar

I am planning on moving the US as a result of my work most likely using TN. I'll be selling my primary residence and will put the money in a saving account at a Canadian bank. I don't want to use this money at the moment due to the poor CAD to USD conversion.

Are there any tax implication the money in the saving account from both the US and Canada apart from being taxed on any interest made from the saving account?

What is the best way to protect your CAD apart from keeping your money in CAD at a Canadian bank and wait for a better time for CAD to USD conversion?

Comment: You'll also need to report the Canadian account as a  foreign account to the US Treasury Department each year...

Comment: That is fine, I don't mind reporting it. 

Say, USD -> CAD is at 1.35 at the moment which is a bit discouraging to go through the conversion. However, say in few years it becomes par and if I do the conversion then, will there be any tax implications?